# Building and linking lua from source via makefile

Tags: lua, c++17, gnu-make, static-linking

I've tried to compile and link lua with my application.  This is my makefile:

```
app.o: app.cpp
    g++ -c app.cpp

PATH_LUA=../lua-5.4.3/src
LUA= \
$(PATH_LUA)/lapi.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lauxlib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lbaselib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lcode.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lcorolib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lctype.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ldblib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ldebug.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ldo.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ldump.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lfunc.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lgc.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/linit.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/liolib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/llex.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lmathlib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lmem.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/loadlib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lobject.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lopcodes.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/loslib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lparser.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lstate.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lstring.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lstrlib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ltable.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ltablib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/ltm.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lundump.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lutf8lib.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lvm.c \
$(PATH_LUA)/lzio.c

libLua.so:
    g++ -shared $(LUA) -fPIC -o lua/libLua.so
 
all: libLua.so app.o
    g++ -o app app.o -I$(PATH_LUA) -lLua -Llua -ldl
```

The compilation works fine, but something is wrong with the linkage, because I get tons of `undefined references to "lua_XYZ-function"`. The `undefined reference to lua_tointegerx` for example makes no sense, since its implementation is located in `lapi.c` which is in the file-list above.

(INB4: "This is a duplicate question!" … I've tried my best to check them all.)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile *lua* as c++-code explicitly.

You do this by including

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
```

*instead* of
`#include <lua.hpp>` which includes that `extern "C" {...}` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the `libLua.so` (by the way, personally I think it's a really bad idea to name your library the same name as the standard library, just uppercase... there's no way that can't bite you or someone in the rear at some point) in the `lua` subdirectory but you don't tell the linker where to find it.

Then, you list `liblua.a` as the prerequisite, but you have no actual rule to build `liblua.a`, which means make will come up with one based on its internal rules... whatever rule it uses will *certainly* not include all your source files (how could it know?).

If you show us the actual output of running make (before all the error messages) it should be pretty clear this has gone wrong from the beginning.

Speaking from a strictly makefile perspective, it's virtually always wrong to have the name of the file your recipe builds be different than the name of the target in the makefile.

Comment: Maybe your naming already bit me: maybe the prerequisite `liblua.a` is supposed to reference the standard lua?  Is that in your local directory somehow?  All is confusion and chaos... I recommend you revisit your naming, determine what `-L` linker options you need, and if you still can't figure out the problem edit your question showing the make command you ran, the compile commands and link commands make invoked, and the _FIRST_ set of errors generated by the linker: the first errors are always the most important ones.  The last errors are more likely to be uninteresting.

Comment: I copied the wrong filename concerning the .a file while composing this question here. I've tried `.so` of course in my makefile.
Also please notice that the standard lua-library is named `lua`. *My* library has a capital `L`.  First error: `/usr/bin/ld: app.o: in function "delay(lua_State*)": app.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to "lua_tointegerx"` (Yes I am sure.)
And I tell the linker that my library is in `./lua`.

Comment: I know you named it with a capital L.  See my comment _I think it's a really bad idea to name your library the same name as the standard library, **just uppercase**_.  In any event, there's nothing in your makefile to tell us what is wrong, so the issue must be something that's not here.  Make sure there aren't any other libLua.so or libLua.a libraries around.  You can also add the `-Wl,-t` option to your link line to have the linker print the libraries it finds.  And you can run `nm -o lua/libLua.so | grep lua_tointegerx` to see if it's there and what its linkage is.

Comment: If had to guess, without knowing anything about Lua, you have to provide some compile-time option if you want to link it into a shared library to force all the symbols to be public.  If you make it a static library instead does it work?

Comment: The lib list via `-Wl,-t` definitely contains `lua/libLua.so` and 
`nm -o lua/libLua.so | grep lua_tointegerx` gives me `lua/libLua.so:000000000000b996 T _Z14lua_tointegerxP9lua_StateiPi`
Seems correct, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it doesn't even link if I compile everything at once via `g++ -o app app.cpp ../lua-5.4.3/src/lapi.c ... .c`. I get the same undefined references.